# Conditional probability distribibution for nearbySelection [Optaplanner]

Tags: optaplanner

In a vrp problem, I want to employ different probability distribitions for all `moveSelector`s depending on where in the chain the planning is being done. More concretely, I want to employ a block distribution for the first entity in the chain and parabolic for anywhere else in the (same) chain.

Now, I could configure identical moves one with block distribution and one with parabolic, but this is going to get cluttered very quick. So, instead I am wondering what will happen if I state that in the implemented `NearbyDistanceMeter` the distance is 0 if it is the first entity in the chain and a value > 0 if it is not the first entity. Will this work as intended ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not.
The `NearbyDistanceMeter` should be idempotent (give the same result when called twice), regardless of the state of the planning variables.
In fact, it's called & cached before solving really starts.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I think my approach is idempotent. How I implemented the distance meter is that the distance from any node to any vehicle is 0, this is not state dependent and the vehicle is always the source of any chain. Won't you agree ?